# When I try to echo data from database using php my html page breaked

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make a dynamic page but when I try to echo fetched data in HTML using echo between HTML tags the page structure breaks:

This image is with php code :

[image]

This is image without php code :

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-12">
<div class="intro-text">

    <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>

    <h1 class="intro-lead-in" style="margin-top: 116px;">
        <?php 
            $about = $data['content'];
            $about_intro = explode("India",$about);
            echo $about_intro[0];
        ?>
    </h1>
 <!--   <input style="text-align:center;margin-left:88px;color:white;background-color:#f7b733;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:176px;margin-left:-12px;" class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Tell Me More">  -->
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: just the form got lost ? and where this text coming from you php code ?

Comment: Hey humza thanks for instant reply , the text is coming from data base i using while loop ,

Comment: can you show your code where it's breaking and php version you're using and i want to see full page while you load page with db content

Comment: What is the actual question? Seeing only those two images I can only confirm that something is wrong. Post the relevant code

Comment: hey sry for that i am new here , I edited my post please help me

Comment: View the source code of that <h1> and take a look at what `$about_intro[0]` actually inserts, there might be a closing `</div>`, `</h1>` or something else in it that breaks your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the while loop inside the `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-12">
<div class="intro-text">

    <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>

    <h1 class="intro-lead-in" style="margin-top: 116px;">
        <?php 
            $about = $data['content'];
            $about_intro = explode("India",$about);
            echo $about_intro[0];
        ?>
    </h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
 <!--   <input style="text-align:center;margin-left:88px;color:white;background-color:#f7b733;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:176px;margin-left:-12px;" class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Tell Me More">  -->
</div>
</div>
```